# Why does requests library fail on this URL?

Tags: debugging, browser, python-requests

I have [a url](http://www.courts.wa.gov/index.cfm?fa=controller.managefiles&filePath=Opinions&fileName=875146.pdf). When I try to access it programmatically, the backend server fails (I don't run the server):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.courts.wa.gov/index.cfm?fa=controller.managefiles&filePath=Opinions&fileName=875146.pdf')
r.status_code  # 200
print r.content
```

When I look at the content, it's an error page, though the status code is 200. If you click the link, it'll work in your browser -- you'll get a PDF -- which is what I expect in r.content. So it works in my browser, but fails in Requests.

To diagnose, I'm trying to eliminate differences between my browser and Requests library. So far I've:

- Disabled Javascript
- Disabled (and deleted) cookies
- Set the User-Agent to be the same in each

But I can't get the thing to work properly in Requests or fail in my browser due to disabling something. Can somebody with a better idea of browser-magic help me diagnose and solve this?

Comment: Might it be because the Content-length is unspecified?

Comment: No, I believe that's generally acceptable, though frowned on. An oddity, but see my comment below for the bigger oddity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the request work in Chrome? If so, you can open the web inspector and right-click the request to copy it as a curl command. Then you'll have access to all the headers, params, and request body, which you can play around with to see which are triggering the failure you're seeing with the requests library.

Comment: It works in Chrome, and the copied cURL command worked as well. From there, I took played whak-a-header until it failed. If you don't provide a User-Agent, it fails. Not sure why my other code wasn't working before, but this is reproducible now, thanks. I declare whoever manages this server my new nemesis.

Comment: @Lukasa and I who help maintain requests have pre-emptively declared all administrators of such services our nemeses. Welcome to our world. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a server that discriminates based on User-Agent. This works:

```
import requests
S = requests.Session()
S.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)'})
r = S.get('http://www.courts.wa.gov/index.cfm?fa=controller.managefiles&filePath=Opinions&fileName=875146.pdf')

with open('dl.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. See my comment on @ryan's answer.